# Share button looks disabled

Tags: android, facebook, share, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm trying to use a share button in my application, but it looks as if it was disabled:

[image: disabled share button]

I already initialize the sdk:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
}
```

I also have the manifest correctly configured like the documentation suggest:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

The button in the view is like this:

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/share"
              android:id="@+id/share_on_fb_button"
              bind:onClick="shareOnFBButtonClick"/>
```

What could be the problem? Why is the button disabled? Should I implement login functionality in my app? Or I only need to have facebook application on the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButtonBase:

```
/**
 * Sets the share content on the button.
 * @param shareContent The share content.
 */
public void setShareContent(final ShareContent shareContent) {
    this.shareContent = shareContent;
    if (!enabledExplicitlySet) {
        internalSetEnabled(canShare());
    }
}
```

Calling setShareContent to enable the shareButton, try it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ShareButton fbShareButton = (ShareButton) findViewById(R.id.share_on_fb_button);
    ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
            .build();
    fbShareButton.setShareContent(content);
}
```

Note:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

"When you implement sharing, your app should not pre-fill any content to be shared. This is inconsistent with Facebook Platform Policy, see Facebook Platform Policy, 2.3."

Comment: I wasn't setting the content to share. This solve the problem ;)

Comment: This works, but if I want to share a photo, the button is still disabled