# Facebook "Share" button is disabled when sharing photo in android app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using the code below to share a photo on facebook. But the button is disabled. I have tried the code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198728/share-button-looks-disabled) and I was able to make it work. Here is my code:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_information);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setCaption("Hello World!")
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();

    shareButton = (ShareButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonShare);
    shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

Comment: Ever get any answers to this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing my tests on a virtual device that had no facebook app installed. That was what is causing the problem. When I installed my app on an actual device, everything worked exactly as I wanted them to.

Answer (score 2):

Okay this is late but it took me a long time to figure this out so I thought I would share the solution here. From the Facebook Developers site:

> People can share photos from your app to Facebook with the Share Dialog or with a custom interface.
>
> The photos must be less than 12MB in size
>
> People need the native Facebook for Android app installed, version 7.0 or higher

So the bottom line: you have to have the Facebook Android app installed to use the share button or the Share Dialog for photos. With the app installed the button will enable once you set the content.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. I had the same question and this solved it for me!