# Unexpected Cast to ShareButton [WrongViewCast] Error on Release Build Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook-share, release-builds

I have Facebook Share button in one of my Activities of Android App built in Android Studio. On Build Type Debug, it works perfectly fine. But when changed to Release, Build Fails with the following error.

```
Error:(190) Error: Unexpected cast to ShareButton: layout tag was ImageView [WrongViewCast]
```

This is happening with FB ShareButton only.

Can anyone help?

Activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_news"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context="com.*****.*****.News">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMainImage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:maxWidth="70dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgUserImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_app" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblChangePasswordTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgMainImage"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/news_headline_tint"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:onClick="logOut"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgMainImage"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblFullText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnLogout"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgMainImage"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFBShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lblChangePasswordTitle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:onClick="shareFB"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is the last ImageView.

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: Edited the question by adding XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your XML from:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFBShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lblChangePasswordTitle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:onClick="shareFB"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue" />
```

to:

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
        android:id="@+id/imgFBShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lblChangePasswordTitle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:onClick="shareFB"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue" />
```

The problem you're having is that you're trying to get the functionality from the `ShareButton` and you're casting as such, but unfortunately in your XML you're pointing to an `ImageView` instead of the `ShareButton` class provided by Facebook.

Comment: Thank you! Error gone. Now I just have to run it to see the output.

Comment: Plus 1 for being specific, quick and explanatory. Thank you!

Comment: With this, the FB Share button I am getting is disabled. Can you advise @BradleyWilson?

Comment: can you elaborate on 'disabled'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198728/share-button-looks-disabled

Comment: This is the error that I am facing. But tried this fix and still not working.

Comment: what happened when you tried the solution on that question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141543/discussion-between-mohammed-akhtar-zuberi-and-bradley-wilson).